# Why does my very very simple for loop throw a TypeError

Tags: python, debugging, range, typeerror, spyder

I have a strange problem in python (using Spyder with python 3.7). I was writing a couple of for loops like so:

```
y=2.55
for x in range(0, 250):
    z = x/y/1000.
```

Very simple stuff however this code randomly decides to throw for the line where the for loop starts:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable.
```

I really don't understand where this is going wrong as it seems like such a simple piece of code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you have a tuple named `range` in your code. Try renaming that tuple into something else, like `my_range`, so to not overwrite the built-in `range` method in your python.

Comment: Oh god i feel really dumb now, it seems like this was indeed the issue, just a dumb mistake i made months ago but didnt come up untill now. I have been using np.linspace for my loops in almost all other scenarios...